# Is there a way to clear the search input of a global search when changing pages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**I have a global search (always in the navbar)**. If the user searches for an ID in the search bar, the user is redirected to a search page where I show a table with all the results for that specific ID. If the user cleans the input field (backspace) the user is redirected to the previous page he/she was on (the user could have searched the ID from the dashboard or any other pages in the app).

But the issues I have now are:

1. The user search for an ID
2. The user is redirected to the search page
3. The user after searching, decide to change page from the sidebar, then goes to any random page (let's say to a dashboard)
4. The input field with that specific ID user searched at the beginning is still present in the search input field, even if the user is now in the dashboard

So basically I need to clean the input field in the search page all the time the user changes the page.

So far I have this:

```
const searchPageRegex = /^\/org\/\d+\/search/;

interface SearchWidgetProps {
  className?: string;
}

const SearchWidget = ({ className }: SearchWidgetProps) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const ref = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const location = useLocation() as Location & {
    state: { from: string | undefined };
  };
  const currentPath = useRef<string>(location.pathname);
  const isSearchPage = searchPageRegex.test(location.pathname);

  const { state } = useLocalState();
  const { organisationId } = useParams();
  const [fromPath, setFromPath] = useState<string>();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchPageRegex.test(currentPath.current) && !isSearchPage) {
      setFromPath(undefined);
    } else if (location.state?.from) {
      setFromPath(location.state.from);
    }
    currentPath.current = location.pathname;
  }, [location.pathname]);

  const onChange = () => {
    if (ref?.current?.value === '') {
      if (fromPath) {
        navigate(fromPath);
      } else {
        navigate('..');
      }
    }
  };

  const onKeyPress: KeyboardEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (event) => {
    if (event.key == 'Enter' && ref.current?.value.trim()) {
      const state = isSearchPage ? undefined : { from: location };
      navigate(`/org/${organisationId}/search?q=${ref.current.value.trim()}`, {
        state
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={`relative h-[42px] ${className}`}>
      <SearchIcon className="absolute left-2 m-2 h-6 w-6 stroke-1" />
      <input
        ref={ref}
        type="text"
        name="search"
        aria-label="Search"
        defaultValue={state.q as string}
        title="Search"
        placeholder="Search ref. or end-to-end id"
        className="h-full w-full rounded-lg border-none bg-white p-2.5 pl-12 shadow-plain hover:shadow-plain-lg focus:shadow-plain-lg focus:outline-0 focus:ring-0"
        onKeyPress={onKeyPress}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchWidget;
```

I was thinking to use useEffect and useNavigate but not completely sure why it does not work and if it is the best approach. Any clues?

Comment: So when do you need to clean the search exactly?

Comment: all the time I change page

Comment: @user19625670 you mean when you search something right?

Comment: maybe you can check the url and if url does not include 'search' word, you clean the search input. If url is usable, I don't think that you need a useEffect. because if user goes to another page, ergo new url and a new page render. so check function would run one time

Comment: I search something, I go to the search page, see the results, but if I change page, I need to clean the search input of the global search (it is always on the navbar)

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition to your search input's `defaultValue`, like so:
(I'm not familiar enough with TypeScript, but this is how it would look in JS)

```
<input
  ref={ref}
  // Other attributes
  defaultValue={isSearchPage ? state.q : ""} // edited to flip the condition
  // Other attributes
/>
```

[Edit]
If the above doesn't work, try the below:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // if it's not search page, reset ref's current value
  if (!isSearchPage) {
    ref.current.value = ""
  }
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried to add it but it does not work. I tried to replace the ' ' with a random string but i still see the input field as the latest ID i typed

Comment: My bad, sorry, the condition should have been flipped. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it as follow:

```
const searchPageRegex = /^\/org\/\d+\/search/;

interface SearchWidgetProps {
  className?: string;
}

const SearchWidget = ({ className }: SearchWidgetProps) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const ref = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const location = useLocation() as Location & {
    state: { from: string | undefined };
  };
  const currentPath = useRef<string>(location.pathname);
  const isSearchPage = searchPageRegex.test(location.pathname);

  const { state } = useLocalState();
  const { organisationId } = useParams();
  const [fromPath, setFromPath] = useState<string>();
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchPageRegex.test(currentPath.current) && !isSearchPage) {
      setFromPath(undefined);
    } else if (location.state?.from) {
      setFromPath(location.state.from);
    }
    currentPath.current = location.pathname;
  }, [location.pathname]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isSearchPage && state.q) {
      setSearchValue(state.q);
    } else if (!isSearchPage) {
      setSearchValue('');
    }
  }, [location]);

  const onChange = () => {
    setSearchValue(ref?.current?.value || '');
    if (ref?.current?.value === '') {
      if (fromPath) {
        navigate(fromPath);
      } else {
        navigate('..');
      }
    }
  };

  const onKeyPress: KeyboardEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (event) => {
    if (event.key == 'Enter' && ref.current?.value.trim()) {
      const state = isSearchPage ? undefined : { from: location };
      navigate(`/org/${organisationId}/search?q=${ref.current.value.trim()}`, {
        state
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={`relative h-[42px] ${className}`}>
      <SearchIcon className="absolute left-2 m-2 h-6 w-6 stroke-1" />
      <input
        ref={ref}
        type="text"
        name="search"
        aria-label="Search"
        value={searchValue}
        title="Search"
        placeholder="Search ref. or end-to-end id"
        className="h-full w-full rounded-lg border-none bg-white p-2.5 pl-12 shadow-plain hover:shadow-plain-lg focus:shadow-plain-lg focus:outline-0 focus:ring-0"
        onKeyPress={onKeyPress}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchWidget;
```